# How to make select statement in cshtml file?

Tags: html, sql, asp.net-core, razor

I am making a single page web application, that is supposed to show sample data from my department in a hospital on a big TV screen.

VS 2019
ASP.net core web app

I have created a connection string in the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <connectionStrings>
            <clear />
            <add name="MADS" 
            connectionString="server=11.111.11.111:2222;database=XXX;userid=UserID;password=PassWord;"/>
        </connectionStrings>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have now created a table in my index.cshtml file. Question is, how do I use my connection string? The goal is to get the result of a SELECT query in a < td > tag.

default.cshtml file:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th width="100px">Name</th>
        <td width="100px">Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Samples today</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Samples week</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Samples YTD</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Waiting</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </td>
</table>
```

I have made the SQL scripts in Oracle SQL developer, I just do not know how to insert them here - and use my connection string.

Hope you can help me. :)

Comment: I think you are missing a part of the picture. The query to the database is done server-side and the results are passed to the view/page to display it. Perhaps you should read some tutorial on razor page and how they work.

Comment: Well, I was going to explain every step but you are missing so much. Entities, Data access layer, context etc. So you should start some tutorial to understand the logic of MVC. You can find here : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/mvc

Comment: You can try to use EFCore in .net core,here is an official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0).